# C++ Lambda error on Mac (gcc out of date?)

Tags: c++, macos

I'm learning some C++ on my Mac and when I got to Lambda's I get a compiler error (expected expression) when the lambda is reached: apply(^HERE^[].

```
void apply(void (*f)(int)) {
    f(10);
}

void output() {
    apply([](int data) {
        printf("data: %d\n", data);
    });
}
```

Entering "g++ -v" in terminal I get:

> Configured with:
>   --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0.0 Thread model: posix
>   InstalledDir:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

So is my Lambda code wrong or is my version of the compiler out of date? I keep Xcode updated (version 9 now) so I expected to a have a version of C++ newer than 2011.

EDIT:

The solution is to compile using the command below. g++ by default doesn't support c++ 11 I apparently.

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
```

Comment: Not getting why it's `g++` but LLVM and Clang.

Comment: Your compiler is out of date. A lambda is convertible to a plain function pointer, provided that the signatures match and the lambda does not capture anything.

Comment: No, looks like Xcode 9 should support it.

Comment: `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1` -- gcc 4.2.1 header files.

Comment: Figured it out. clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++. Thanks guys.